# Can not execute application with maps on Android device running 4.0.3 ICS

Tags: android, google-maps

Well just finished an application with some basic map functionality. Was testing across multiple sdk to ensure proper execution and support.

Found that it would not execute on a Tablet that I have which **runs on Android 4.0.3 ICS**. (Note: Standard MAPS and NAVIGATION apps work fine).

Executing the same for an emulator wont raise any exception and run fine. Tried to Google around, found that the **exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.security.MessageDigest** is  caused due to some firmware compatibility / mis-match with Google MAPS API / SDK.

Certain other people [**suggest to use java.security.MessageDigest**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11407929/383414) but in this case I / we won't be able to **edit the com.google.maps.jar** on our own. Can you please suggest a work around or some trick to ensure it works for Android 4.0.3 ICS devices

Comment: On which tablet did you test?

Comment: I tried it on Hyundai A7

Comment: 07-17 00:33:01.648: E/AndroidRuntime(1626): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-17 00:33:01.648: E/AndroidRuntime(1626): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.security.MessageDigest
07-17 00:33:01.648: E/AndroidRuntime(1626):  at com.google.android.maps.KeyHelper.getSignatureFingerprint(KeyHelper.java:60)
07-17 00:33:01.648: E/AndroidRuntime(1626):  at com.google.android.maps.MapActivity.createMap(MapActivity.java:552)
07-17 00:33:01.648: E/AndroidRuntime(1626):  at com.google.android.maps.MapActivity.onCreate(MapActivity.java:422)

Comment: Found a work around. One thing was sure that the device running Android 4.0.3 ICS had some issue with Google Maps API. So tried to Google for any libraries specific to Android 4.0.3 ICS. Found this gapps-ics-20120429-signed.zip [http://www.mediafire.com/?owj7hj310var5rq]. Downloaded and connected by device to my Computer. Used following to install the library 1. adb remount
2. adb push system/etc/permissions/com.google.android.maps.xml /system/etc/permissions
3. adb push system/framework/com.google.android.maps.jar /system/framework
4. adb reboot , Got everything to work fine. Hope this helps

Comment: Hi Mistry Hardik , I got the same problem, but i get the crash log from my users. how to you fix this problem? it seems to me that it is the problem of the device not about the program. can you give me some hints on that?

Comment: Yes justicepenny, the issue is with the device and not on the application side. Need to add missing com.google.android.maps.jar file to the system

Comment: Please add the answer and mark it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a work around. One thing was sure that the device running Android 4.0.3 ICS had some issue with Google Maps API. So tried to Google for any libraries specific to Android 4.0.3 ICS. Found this gapps-ics-20120429-signed.zip [mediafire.com/?owj7hj310var5rq]. Downloaded and connected by device to my Computer. Used following to install the library 1. adb remount 2. adb push system/etc/permissions/com.google.android.maps.xml /system/etc/permissions 3. adb push system/framework/com.google.android.maps.jar /system/framework 4. adb reboot , Got everything to work fine. Hope this helps