# How to get user's google api version on android?

Tags: android, google-api

I'm facing some rare problem. I have a device running on Android API 14. Anytime I try to use `MapActivity` I get the same error - `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.security.MessageDigest`. On other 99% devices it works perfect.

After some digging, I've found root of the problem.

> The error is the result of a device manufacturer or ROM creator using
>   an older maps library with a new version of Android. (more at
>   [What is 'android.security.MessageDigest''?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11407685/what-is-android-security-messagedigest))

The functionality of MapActivity isn't required for application, so I want to check if user has such device.

How can I get user's google api version on android?

Answer (score 0):

Use [Google map v2](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/).

You want to use Google map console to register SHA-1 for signing the key in Google api console.

The complete tutorial can be found [here](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidGoogleMaps/article.html).

Comment: Thanks for reply. Google map v2 doesn't use android.security.MessageDigest? Are you completely sure?