# Android Map Application has stopped unexpectedly

Tags: android, google-maps

I am working on an Android Project of using goolge map.
But when I try to run it on a tablet or HTC phone, it says the application has stopped unexpectedly. What kind of setting do I need to do, like adding library files and etc.

I have used my API key as well, so if this apps runs on a device, can I view the map or only the grid? what do we mean by signing the app?

MainActivity.java

```
package com.sulav.maptravis2;

import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends MapActivity {
MapView map;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    try{
    map=(MapView) findViewById(R.id.mvMain);
    map.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    }
    catch(Exception e){}
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}

}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

 <com.google.android.maps.MapView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"        
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/mvMain"
    android:apiKey="AIzaSyBxPKfOUpiOK981HFNcXi6szt0Dn__tQko"
    />

</RelativeLayout>
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.sulav.maptravis2"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="7"
    android:targetSdkVersion="8" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps"/>

    <activity
        android:name="com.sulav.maptravis2.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

logcat output:

```
05-24 12:06:46.285: I/dalvikvm(7686): Could not find method android.security.MessageDigest.getInstance, referenced from method com.google.android.maps.KeyHelper.getSignatureFingerprint
05-24 12:06:46.285: W/dalvikvm(7686): VFY: unable to resolve static method 153: Landroid/security/MessageDigest;.getInstance (Ljava/lang/String;)Landroid/security/MessageDigest;
05-24 12:06:46.285: D/dalvikvm(7686): VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x0038
05-24 12:06:46.295: D/AndroidRuntime(7686): Shutting down VM
05-24 12:06:46.295: W/dalvikvm(7686): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409fe1f8)
05-24 12:06:46.305: E/AndroidRuntime(7686): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-24 12:06:46.305: E/AndroidRuntime(7686): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.security.MessageDigest
05-24 12:06:46.305: E/AndroidRuntime(7686):     at com.google.android.maps.KeyHelper.getSignatureFingerprint(KeyHelper.java:60)
05-24 12:06:46.305: E/AndroidRuntime(7686):     at com.google.android.maps.MapActivity.createMap(MapActivity.java:552)
05-24 12:06:46.305: E/AndroidRuntime(7686):     at com.google.android.maps.MapActivity.onCreate(MapActivity.java:422)
05-24 12:06:46.305: E/AndroidRuntime(7686):     at com.sulav.maptravis2.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:13)
05-24 12:06:46.305: E/AndroidRuntime(7686):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
05-24 12:06:46.305: E/AndroidRuntime(7686):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
05-24 12:06:46.305: E/AndroidRuntime(7686):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
05-24 12:06:46.305: E/AndroidRuntime(7686):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
05-24 12:06:46.305: E/AndroidRuntime(7686):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
05-24 12:06:46.305: E/AndroidRuntime(7686):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
05-24 12:06:46.305: E/AndroidRuntime(7686):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-24 12:06:46.305: E/AndroidRuntime(7686):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-24 12:06:46.305: E/AndroidRuntime(7686):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
05-24 12:06:46.305: E/AndroidRuntime(7686):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-24 12:06:46.305: E/AndroidRuntime(7686):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-24 12:06:46.305: E/AndroidRuntime(7686):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
05-24 12:06:46.305: E/AndroidRuntime(7686):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
05-24 12:06:46.305: E/AndroidRuntime(7686):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: please post your logcat output

Comment: What error you getting? can you post your error log?

Comment: are you using map api v1 which is depreceated ?. use api v2

Comment: @Raghunandan i am using api v2

Comment: @SulavTimsina it does not look like you are using api v2. pls follow the link @ https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start

Comment: looking at your code it seems to me like you are using api v1. have a look at these links to use v2 http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidGoogleMaps/article.html and https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start

Comment: i have used api v2 but may be my code is for v1 since it is from an old tutorial.how do i change/edit the code so the it works with api v2  @prvn

Comment: There are a lot of things to change follow the links i have given above if you are stuck somewhere let me know i will help you

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you just failed to paste it in but it appears your layout is missing this at the top.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

Regardless check this link out:
[What is 'android.security.MessageDigest''?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11407685/what-is-android-security-messagedigest)

Comment: adding that line also doesn't help :(

Comment: Ok what are you trying to run this on?

Comment: On a HCL Tablet android 4.0.3. it has no GPS

Comment: Just curious... Try running your app in an emulator to see if you get the same error.

Comment: I am having problem with my emulators(AVDs).recently ,its been some days,they start very slow,or get stuck on the "android" screen.

Comment: I edited my answer, it seems that this error is related to your device manufacturer using an old google maps library but you should be able to fix it.

Comment: It runs on HTC aria. but it doesn't show tha map.but only the grid with a google logo at the bottom left of the screen(map grid)

Comment: The grid has to do with your api key. You have likely created an api key that works with a signed application. You will need one that works with your debug signing key. See here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#obtaining_an_api_key

Comment: so u mean if i don't want to upload it to google play i dont need the api key? how do i get the debug signing key?

Comment: No you need the a pi key to make the map display but you need a key based off your production signing key for production and a key based on your development or debug signing key when developing. The link I posted in the above comment explains it.